# how to get jenkins parameter's default value

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to have a check in jenkins job, where if the jenkins parameters have been modified then I want to display an Input modal to proceed or abort the job .But for that I need to verify if the parameters have been modified.

So, I can get modified parameters value in jenkins job, but how to retrieve default values of those parameters so that I can verify if any parameters have been modified?

Answer (score -1):

```
def DEFAULT_VALUE = "42"

pipeline {
   agent any
   parameters { string(name: 'MY_PARAM', defaultValue: DEFAULT_VALUE, description: '') }     
   stages {
      stage('Example') {
          steps { 
             script {
                if (params.MY_PARAM == DEFAULT_VALUE) {
                   echo 'Default value used'
                } else {
                   echo 'Non-default value used'
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```